# CryptDecrypt fails with ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when called for openssl encrypted data

Tags: c++, winapi, encryption, openssl, rsa

I'm trying to use encryption/decryption functions available in Windows.

I generated RSA key pair in PuTTYgen, extracted private and public keys to separate pem files. Then I use OpenSSL to test those keys by encrypting and then decrypting some message.

```
openssl.exe rsautl -in input.txt -out encrypted.bin -inkey public_key_4096_puttygen.pem -encrypt -oaep -pubin
openssl.exe rsautl -in encrypted.bin -out decrypted.txt -inkey private_key_4096_puttygen.pem -decrypt -oaep
```

At this step everything is fine.

Then I take the private key data into sample C++ program written in Visual Studio C++. I call the following functions: [CryptAcquireContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptacquirecontexta), [CryptImportKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptimportkey), [CryptEncrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptencrypt) and [CryptDecrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecrypt) to test encryption/decryption chain. And also there is everything allright.

Finally I wand to encrypt some data by openssl command and try to decrypt it in C++ program with above functions. And [CryptDecrypt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptdecrypt) returns `FALSE` (`GetLastError` returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`).

Here is the program code:

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "stdio.h"

#define KEY_BUFFER_LENGTH (8 * 1024)

void main()
{
    LPCSTR encryptedBase64 = "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";

    HCRYPTPROV provider;
    BYTE privKey[] = {0x30, 0x82, 0x09, 0x26, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x82, 0x02, 0x01, 0x00, 0xAE, 0xFF, 0x2C, 0x1E, 0xBD, 0x7A, 0xF3, 0xC0, 0x71, 0x56, 0x6D, 0x4C, 0x54, 0x59, 0x77, 0xCE, 0x88, 0xFB, 0x59, 0xB9, 0xB7, 0xDA, 0xB8, 0xCA, 0xBB, 0x67, 0x05, 0xF0, 0x50, 0xB6, 0x6C, 0x41, 0xE3, 0xB9, 0x7E, 0x36, 0xA3, 0x49, 0x13, 0x42, 0xA9, 0xBB, 0x51, 0x02, 0x97, 0xB2, 0xBF, 0x76, 0xB6, 0xFA, 0x1E, 0xCE, 0x00, 0xE7, 0xA7, 0xF8, 0xE2, 0x00, 0x08, 0x96, 0xE0, 0x9F, 0x21, 0x71, 0xAB, 0x48, 0xCB, 0xC6, 0x83, 0x63, 0xBE, 0xB9, 0x0F, 0x89, 0x66, 0x70, 0x58, 0x40, 0xC1, 0x8E, 0xAC, 0xC8, 0xE1, 0x97, 0xCF, 0x40, 0xE9, 0xE5, 0xE5, 0x35, 0x71, 0xB2, 0x28, 0xA6, 0x00, 0x2A, 0xC6, 0x39, 0x59, 0x6F, 0x81, 0xFB, 0xFC, 0x7A, 0xAC, 0x24, 0xAF, 0xB2, 0x9D, 0xFD, 0xAD, 0x91, 0xCE, 0xC8, 0xD2, 0x9E, 0x4A, 0xE2, 0x33, 0xA4, 0xB3, 0x37, 0x25, 0x41, 0x21, 0x4C, 0x8D, 0xB3, 0x9A, 0xB7, 0x96, 0x35, 0xF2, 0x95, 0x7B, 0x8A, 0x0F, 0x8E, 0x37, 0xA2, 0x15, 0xFE, 0x6B, 0xC1, 0x7D, 0x51, 0xA3, 0xE3, 0xC4, 0x13, 0xE8, 0x8B, 0x95, 0xE6, 0x10, 0x44, 0x40, 0x11, 0x6D, 0xA5, 0x4B, 0x33, 0x69, 0x2C, 0x21, 0xF7, 0x09, 0x5E, 0x09, 0x8B, 0x9C, 0x3C, 0xB3, 0xD8, 0xF9, 0xA8, 0xAF, 0x69, 0x3B, 0xBF, 0x52, 0xB6, 0xB2, 0x08, 0x2A, 0x1E, 0x5D, 0x3A, 0xCB, 0x8B, 0xC4, 0xBF, 0xA3, 0xE8, 0x20, 0x62, 0x43, 0xBB, 0x12, 0x74, 0x04, 0xE7, 0xEE, 0x3A, 0x60, 0xF4, 0x9F, 0x92, 0xA9, 0x57, 0x54, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0x16, 0x84, 0x3E, 0x60, 0x90, 0xD6, 0x1E, 0xD2, 0x9B, 0xCA, 0x1B, 0x78, 0x6E, 0xE5, 0x98, 0x68, 0x2A, 0x6D, 0x52, 0x0F, 0x54, 0x3E, 0x19, 0x8A, 0xFC, 0xC2, 0x7B, 0x67, 0x00, 0x68, 0x2B, 0x67, 0x0F, 0x2D, 0x56, 0xB2, 0xE5, 0x6F, 0x6C, 0x05, 0x7B, 0x6B, 0xA4, 0x32, 0x31, 0x97, 0x52, 0x5E, 0x38, 0x0F, 0x3F, 0x24, 0x6B, 0xF9, 0x35, 0xE0, 0x88, 0xA4, 0x26, 0x49, 0x12, 0xF1, 0x00, 0xEC, 0x2D, 0x80, 0x0B, 0x15, 0xA7, 0x32, 0x0C, 0xDD, 0xA2, 0x0C, 0xA7, 0xB8, 0x3C, 0xA0, 0x41, 0xFB, 0x3D, 0xB5, 0x4D, 0xBE, 0xFC, 0x72, 0x43, 0xDD, 0x96, 0x59, 0x1E, 0x76, 0xA2, 0xE1, 0x8A, 0x0F, 0x52, 0xF1, 0x86, 0x9B, 0x6D, 0x5E, 0x81, 0x14, 0xDE, 0x39, 0xF6, 0xB7, 0xFB, 0xEF, 0xB8, 0x74, 0xAB, 0xDA, 0x93, 0xC5, 0xB0, 0x86, 0xEF, 0x11, 0xD3, 0xC2, 0x95, 0x09, 0x06, 0x05, 0x00, 0x2E, 0x58, 0xE6, 0xFA, 0xEE, 0xE1, 0xC3, 0xA7, 0xF5, 0x4E, 0xE2, 0x93, 0xF9, 0xD9, 0x0F, 0xBE, 0xB5, 0x9A, 0x71, 0xEF, 0xE2, 0x7A, 0xEA, 0xF7, 0x17, 0x30, 0xA2, 0x51, 0xD0, 0x15, 0x4A, 0x76, 0xBD, 0x09, 0x95, 0x78, 0x4F, 0x5E, 0xC3, 0xF0, 0x22, 0xD5, 0x33, 0x87, 0x25, 0x9C, 0xF9, 0x1A, 0xA2, 0xA3, 0x7C, 0x6C, 0xF8, 0xD0, 0x9E, 0x4A, 0xA8, 0xD7, 0x25, 0x22, 0x47, 0xC9, 0x43, 0x39, 0x68, 0x11, 0x8B, 0x73, 0x6C, 0xF6, 0x84, 0x86, 0x02, 0xA0, 0xF7, 0xC8, 0x8D, 0xB4, 0x28, 0x8A, 0x96, 0x44, 0x76, 0x07, 0x57, 0x4A, 0x51, 0x27, 0xFF, 0xD5, 0x9D, 0xBF, 0x07, 0x2F, 0x00, 0x9E, 0xE5, 0xA8, 0xF8, 0xD6, 0x03, 0xA3, 0xDA, 0x17, 0xAA, 0xC8, 0x73, 0xCB, 0x6B, 0xDD, 0x1C, 0x49, 0x55, 0x87, 0x96, 0x57, 0x8C, 0xF1, 0x2B, 0xC9, 0x49, 0xD7, 0xDE, 0xD2, 0x5A, 0xC5, 0x8E, 0x83, 0x05, 0x93, 0x0C, 0xB1, 0x6F, 0xA8, 0xE8, 0x1F, 0x79, 0x19, 0xB8, 0xDA, 0xE5, 0xCC, 0xEA, 0x73, 0x0B, 0xA8, 0xC7, 0xF2, 0xD7, 0xDA, 0x5D, 0x11, 0xD0, 0x63, 0x70, 0x29, 0x60, 0x41, 0x79, 0x8E, 0xEE, 0x69, 0x15, 0xAB, 0xE8, 0x6B, 0x02, 0xEC, 0x61, 0x3D, 0xAC, 0x5D, 0x02, 0x01, 0x25, 0x02, 0x82, 0x02, 0x00, 0x1C, 0x60, 0xBB, 0x0B, 0xE7, 0x60, 0x0B, 0xDA, 0x04, 0x8A, 0x8E, 0x43, 0xBA, 0xA6, 0xB9, 0x7B, 0x70, 0x28, 0xC2, 0x71, 0x24, 0xBB, 0xAF, 0x43, 0x78, 0x55, 0xE5, 0x49, 0x90, 0x8C, 0x48, 0xE8, 0x17, 0x17, 0x29, 0x39, 0x4A, 0xE9, 0x41, 0x64, 0xC1, 0x93, 0xFF, 0x4C, 0x87, 0x4D, 0x6B, 0x28, 0x01, 0xFF, 0x0B, 0xEA, 0x0D, 0xFC, 0x0D, 0x66, 0xA1, 0x30, 0x70, 0x18, 0x77, 0x73, 0xC0, 0x3B, 0xF2, 0x43, 0x27, 0xF6, 0xAD, 0x85, 0xCB, 0xE6, 0xA8, 0x92, 0xD2, 0x57, 0x68, 0x41, 0xDA, 0x32, 0xCF, 0xE9, 0x39, 0x56, 0xE3, 0x56, 0xA2, 0x78, 0x4E, 0xAE, 0xB8, 0x7D, 0xC1, 0x67, 0x06, 0xF2, 0x2D, 0xFB, 0x76, 0x49, 0x6F, 0x06, 0x44, 0x9E, 0x45, 0x6D, 0xBB, 0xA0, 0x6C, 0xA5, 0xAD, 0x71, 0x97, 0x27, 0x7C, 0x19, 0xAB, 0x47, 0x46, 0xA5, 0x16, 0x24, 0x9E, 0x41, 0xE9, 0xB9, 0x63, 0x16, 0x34, 0xC3, 0xD3, 0x2B, 0x57, 0xC5, 0x36, 0xA0, 0xC4, 0x40, 0x93, 0x66, 0x64, 0x6E, 0x72, 0x56, 0xBA, 0x60, 0x44, 0x17, 0x18, 0xE0, 0xA2, 0x40, 0x26, 0x25, 0x4E, 0xBE, 0xF5, 0xA1, 0xF6, 0x1A, 0xCD, 0xEC, 0xA9, 0x45, 0x6D, 0x4A, 0xA7, 0x92, 0xB5, 0x70, 0x95, 0xE0, 0x54, 0x84, 0x0C, 0xCF, 0x3F, 0x0A, 0x25, 0x5D, 0x4B, 0xAE, 0xEC, 0x70, 0x06, 0xD4, 0x7D, 0xD2, 0x2E, 0xD8, 0x65, 0x18, 0x28, 0x6A, 0xD4, 0xD1, 0xAA, 0x1E, 0x56, 0x04, 0xF9, 0xE0, 0x6B, 0xD2, 0x1D, 0x8F, 0x73, 0xD2, 0x98, 0x00, 0x52, 0xEA, 0x9F, 0x41, 0xEB, 0xEE, 0x70, 0x86, 0x30, 0x8F, 0x60, 0x6C, 0x4A, 0x49, 0xA4, 0xD3, 0xB6, 0x87, 0x6A, 0xD6, 0x72, 0x97, 0xAF, 0x75, 0x71, 0xDA, 0xA0, 0xEA, 0xB7, 0xC0, 0xFB, 0xF2, 0x3A, 0x67, 0xE7, 0x32, 0xE4, 0xC1, 0xF3, 0x7F, 0x26, 0xD3, 0x3F, 0x28, 0xC5, 0x58, 0xA0, 0xE3, 0x78, 0x5F, 0x29, 0x0E, 0x9C, 0xD1, 0x4E, 0xA5, 0x54, 0x2B, 0xBA, 0xF1, 0xF3, 0xA8, 0x2B, 0xD7, 0xDD, 0xBB, 0x84, 0x7E, 0x5C, 0xF9, 0x47, 0x49, 0xA0, 0xC6, 0x01, 0xAE, 0x3C, 0xD4, 0x0C, 0xFA, 0x5C, 0x54, 0x3A, 0x85, 0xD6, 0x27, 0x05, 0xD8, 0xEF, 0x5F, 0x4D, 0x5D, 0xB9, 0xC4, 0x28, 0xE3, 0xBE, 0xEC, 0x2D, 0x34, 0x00, 0x68, 0x71, 0x20, 0x04, 0x98, 0xF3, 0x0F, 0x16, 0x56, 0x9D, 0xD2, 0xF3, 0xC9, 0xB5, 0x30, 0x44, 0xEC, 0x7E, 0x50, 0x0D, 0xD7, 0xBB, 0xB1, 0x24, 0xA1, 0xD5, 0x1F, 0x07, 0xFE, 0x33, 0x2A, 0x76, 0x55, 0xFC, 0xC7, 0xB4, 0x4B, 0x56, 0xAB, 0x9E, 0x1C, 0x1C, 0x30, 0x4A, 0x1F, 0xFB, 0x04, 0xD0, 0xE2, 0xCB, 0x04, 0x22, 0x54, 0x96, 0xE9, 0xD2, 0x47, 0x6B, 0x85, 0x5A, 0xD1, 0x43, 0x66, 0x1F, 0xFF, 0xDE, 0x44, 0x27, 0xA8, 0x7C, 0xDD, 0x24, 0xCD, 0x53, 0x6B, 0x25, 0x2B, 0x59, 0x60, 0x88, 0xD9, 0x1B, 0x8C, 0x95, 0xA4, 0xD9, 0xB7, 0xB7, 0x3C, 0x19, 0x31, 0xB4, 0x20, 0xA9, 0x14, 0x08, 0x8B, 0xE1, 0xAF, 0x04, 0x3D, 0xE2, 0x72, 0x94, 0x75, 0x80, 0x66, 0x9F, 0xDF, 0x55, 0x4B, 0x8F, 0xE5, 0x1B, 0xED, 0xFB, 0x3A, 0x93, 0x16, 0xC8, 0xF6, 0xDC, 0x23, 0x76, 0xDC, 0xC6, 0x70, 0x55, 0x50, 0x7D, 0x05, 0x58, 0xDA, 0x92, 0x90, 0x64, 0xFD, 0x04, 0xD0, 0xAD, 0xE2, 0x5A, 0x88, 0x6F, 0x19, 0xE1, 0xEC, 0xC0, 0x74, 0x2B, 0xE1, 0xC3, 0xEB, 0xEF, 0x7B, 0xD2, 0xBC, 0x13, 0x05, 0xDD, 0x27, 0xC9, 0x8E, 0xB0, 0x47, 0x3D, 0x18, 0x1C, 0xD6, 0x40, 0xF6, 0xA9, 0x6E, 0x7C, 0x7A, 0x36, 0xF3, 0xA9, 0x54, 0x3B, 0x91, 0xAE, 0xF7, 0xF7, 0xCD, 0xDC, 0xCC, 0x3B, 0xB6, 0x8D, 0x18, 0x9F, 0x95, 0xF5, 0x7A, 0xD7, 0x52, 0x37, 0xE5, 0x61, 0x75, 0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xD7, 0x63, 0xD4, 0xFD, 0xB3, 0xE3, 0xE1, 0xCF, 0x53, 0x86, 0xC2, 0x4F, 0x0D, 0x22, 0x77, 0xC5, 0xAD, 0x93, 0x71, 0x16, 0x6D, 0xBB, 0x6C, 0xB5, 0xC6, 0xCC, 0x7B, 0x4C, 0x9F, 0x44, 0x27, 0x2B, 0x0A, 0x70, 0x51, 0x25, 0x67, 0xC6, 0xE7, 0xCF, 0xE9, 0xD7, 0xEA, 0x5A, 0x3B, 0xD3, 0xA5, 0xD2, 0xF2, 0x55, 0x6A, 0xF0, 0xFB, 0xE6, 0x0F, 0xA5, 0x30, 0x4F, 0xDE, 0x7C, 0x32, 0x9B, 0x57, 0xD3, 0x58, 0x42, 0xCB, 0x63, 0x43, 0xCD, 0xAB, 0xEE, 0x09, 0x85, 0x8B, 0x75, 0xDE, 0xD6, 0x28, 0x46, 0x2A, 0xD5, 0x8A, 0xE7, 0x61, 0xB0, 0x72, 0x57, 0x44, 0x50, 0x50, 0xA0, 0x5B, 0x1E, 0x59, 0x9D, 0x72, 0x19, 0x8A, 0xC8, 0xA3, 0xA4, 0xA3, 0x24, 0x43, 0xE7, 0x86, 0xF4, 0x28, 0xCB, 0xE7, 0x5E, 0x86, 0xA2, 0xD9, 0xCC, 0x47, 0x75, 0x0F, 0x1E, 0x59, 0xA7, 0x61, 0xF4, 0x0C, 0x4A, 0x39, 0xA8, 0xFC, 0x3D, 0xA4, 0x44, 0xBF, 0x2F, 0xF2, 0x05, 0x65, 0x59, 0x94, 0x91, 0x10, 0xDF, 0x90, 0x70, 0xA4, 0x03, 0xEA, 0x25, 0x9C, 0xEF, 0x3A, 0xBE, 0x35, 0xDE, 0xC3, 0x67, 0xC1, 0xBF, 0x48, 0x14, 0x94, 0xC4, 0xFA, 0xD8, 0x77, 0xDE, 0x81, 0x62, 0x00, 0x3C, 0xC2, 0x62, 0x35, 0x04, 0x6E, 0x40, 0x19, 0xC5, 0x96, 0xFD, 0x15, 0xA1, 0x3D, 0x83, 0x18, 0x55, 0x86, 0x1A, 0x94, 0x0C, 0x20, 0x86, 0x2C, 0xA7, 0x3A, 0xE7, 0xA8, 0xF8, 0xB8, 0xA2, 0x72, 0xB4, 0x92, 0x20, 0x13, 0xA9, 0x99, 0xF7, 0x8C, 0x1C, 0x20, 0x96, 0x98, 0x05, 0x98, 0x08, 0xE7, 0xC8, 0x11, 0x18, 0x88, 0x5E, 0xE8, 0x25, 0x81, 0xA3, 0x34, 0x8F, 0x6A, 0x74, 0x77, 0x5F, 0x42, 0x18, 0x34, 0xCC, 0x1F, 0x6E, 0xD3, 0xE0, 0x2B, 0x82, 0xA1, 0xCD, 0x85, 0x49, 0xF6, 0xCB, 0xF5, 0x6F, 0x34, 0xC0, 0x6F, 0xF3, 0x69, 0xAF, 0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xCF, 0xFD, 0xB1, 0x5F, 0x2D, 0x24, 0xBB, 0xBA, 0x6B, 0xE9, 0xAF, 0xD9, 0x27, 0xE7, 0x78, 0x7E, 0x37, 0xCC, 0x53, 0x3B, 0x78, 0x11, 0x80, 0xA9, 0x6C, 0x94, 0xAC, 0xA5, 0xDE, 0xAB, 0x6E, 0x61, 0x08, 0x6F, 0x15, 0xBF, 0xD5, 0x3D, 0x7A, 0x37, 0xDB, 0xC0, 0x19, 0x1D, 0xEF, 0x56, 0x0F, 0x11, 0xDD, 0x7B, 0xB2, 0x93, 0x52, 0x01, 0x8A, 0x08, 0x06, 0xD8, 0x0E, 0x55, 0xB2, 0x10, 0x83, 0x0D, 0x3D, 0x24, 0x44, 0xF9, 0x53, 0x89, 0xDA, 0xF3, 0x5B, 0xE7, 0xFB, 0x71, 0x82, 0xE3, 0xE3, 0x13, 0x91, 0x46, 0x73, 0x79, 0x3B, 0xCD, 0x45, 0x91, 0x69, 0x17, 0x45, 0xE1, 0xAE, 0x63, 0x8F, 0x49, 0x2F, 0x40, 0x66, 0x86, 0x30, 0xAD, 0x71, 0x55, 0x0F, 0xF9, 0xE5, 0xA3, 0xF6, 0x6D, 0x7F, 0x90, 0x32, 0x66, 0xC0, 0xA0, 0x00, 0x9E, 0xC1, 0x05, 0x70, 0x68, 0x6D, 0x6D, 0x14, 0x8C, 0x96, 0xEB, 0xFC, 0x4A, 0x9A, 0x4A, 0x91, 0xA0, 0x3E, 0x82, 0x14, 0x3E, 0xC4, 0x41, 0x04, 0x0A, 0xAA, 0xBF, 0x08, 0x68, 0x2C, 0xF5, 0x0D, 0xD1, 0x71, 0x56, 0x9C, 0xB5, 0xD1, 0xA0, 0xA1, 0xC9, 0xC6, 0xDF, 0x61, 0x20, 0xFE, 0x7B, 0x90, 0x69, 0x52, 0xA0, 0x80, 0x27, 0x56, 0xDC, 0x95, 0x1A, 0x02, 0xE1, 0xF5, 0x39, 0x61, 0xFB, 0x08, 0x53, 0x02, 0x8D, 0x3D, 0xAD, 0x5A, 0xB9, 0x39, 0x97, 0x39, 0xD7, 0xA1, 0x84, 0x5B, 0xC3, 0x28, 0xF0, 0x30, 0x95, 0x7E, 0x5D, 0xF6, 0xDC, 0xD2, 0x3E, 0x0C, 0xAB, 0xDF, 0x2D, 0xDA, 0x64, 0xA2, 0xE9, 0x4B, 0x88, 0x82, 0x46, 0x42, 0xA4, 0xF7, 0xFB, 0x74, 0x36, 0xD3, 0x8D, 0xF6, 0x64, 0xF6, 0xED, 0x53, 0x0A, 0x56, 0xE5, 0x63, 0x98, 0xA4, 0xA6, 0x24, 0x29, 0x0D, 0xD3, 0x67, 0x86, 0x58, 0x5C, 0x9C, 0x18, 0x89, 0x30, 0xF3, 0xB0, 0xED, 0xEE, 0x69, 0xB3, 0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x00, 0x57, 0x51, 0xFC, 0x66, 0xDA, 0x39, 0xCA, 0x3F, 0x4B, 0x60, 0x25, 0x42, 0xA4, 0x75, 0xC1, 0xDA, 0x84, 0xA3, 0x8E, 0xB6, 0x10, 0xCF, 0x71, 0x42, 0xC6, 0x37, 0x38, 0xE7, 0xB6, 0x30, 0x62, 0xE7, 0xEF, 0x79, 0xA4, 0x5B, 0x45, 0xBF, 0x57, 0x0F, 0x19, 0x9C, 0xB8, 0xF4, 0x26, 0x17, 0x88, 0x6A, 0x46, 0x91, 0x54, 0xDE, 0x3C, 0x9B, 0x89, 0xCD, 0x58, 0xC6, 0x6E, 0xF4, 0x14, 0x84, 0x2A, 0x86, 0x1C, 0xDC, 0xCE, 0xFE, 0xBA, 0x9F, 0x7D, 0x0D, 0x79, 0x7B, 0x54, 0x36, 0xB4, 0x48, 0xFB, 0x92, 0x11, 0x5D, 0x7D, 0x80, 0x65, 0xDF, 0xBF, 0xA6, 0xD6, 0x81, 0x6C, 0xCB, 0x63, 0x35, 0xD1, 0x4D, 0xAA, 0xCC, 0x15, 0xAB, 0x49, 0x42, 0xBE, 0xAD, 0xD6, 0x56, 0xF1, 0x85, 0x93, 0xFF, 0xA2, 0xFC, 0xCE, 0xCC, 0x66, 0x22, 0x62, 0x28, 0x89, 0x96, 0xAE, 0xB9, 0x7A, 0xBC, 0xE2, 0x63, 0x47, 0xCE, 0xE2, 0xCC, 0xE1, 0xBB, 0x01, 0x66, 0x76, 0xDF, 0x97, 0xCA, 0x5E, 0xD3, 0x06, 0xD7, 0x2C, 0xB8, 0x0B, 0x24, 0x2E, 0x7D, 0xF3, 0x83, 0x94, 0x5A, 0xF3, 0x3E, 0xA2, 0x3E, 0xD2, 0x01, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xB1, 0xEE, 0xFD, 0xE9, 0x0E, 0x00, 0x42, 0x4A, 0x53, 0x1F, 0x8D, 0x13, 0x0E, 0x93, 0x17, 0xF0, 0x79, 0x26, 0x97, 0x28, 0x54, 0xE0, 0x80, 0xB8, 0x9B, 0x29, 0x97, 0x3B, 0x35, 0x19, 0xAC, 0x52, 0x12, 0x1A, 0x48, 0x50, 0x14, 0x11, 0xCE, 0x4F, 0xB1, 0xF6, 0x2D, 0x66, 0xF3, 0x36, 0xEB, 0x64, 0x5B, 0x65, 0x59, 0x51, 0xCE, 0xED, 0x82, 0xD3, 0x2D, 0x88, 0x75, 0xA2, 0x29, 0x72, 0x95, 0x76, 0xFD, 0x34, 0x53, 0x94, 0x16, 0x66, 0x91, 0x42, 0x4B, 0x3A, 0x3E, 0xEA, 0xF7, 0xFC, 0x7F, 0x68, 0xB7, 0xB1, 0x7F, 0xDD, 0xB2, 0x93, 0x9B, 0x67, 0x71, 0x56, 0x98, 0xD8, 0x64, 0xBC, 0xA0, 0x77, 0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x00, 0x27, 0x59, 0x82, 0x6B, 0xF3, 0xC8, 0xAD, 0xE4, 0xFF, 0xA8, 0xC0, 0x67, 0x5A, 0x93, 0x93, 0x56, 0x26, 0x3B, 0x69, 0xB1, 0x4E, 0x11, 0x26, 0x2D, 0xE4, 0x1C, 0x20, 0xA9, 0xC2, 0x57, 0xC8, 0xC6, 0x3F, 0xDD, 0xAA, 0x2B, 0x36, 0x2E, 0x39, 0xB7, 0x8A, 0x70, 0x73, 0x74, 0x5D, 0xB6, 0x55, 0xE0, 0xC9, 0x09, 0x90, 0x7C, 0xBC, 0x7C, 0xD4, 0xEC, 0xC3, 0x06, 0x47, 0xE6, 0xB2, 0xFC, 0x34, 0x78, 0x20, 0x52, 0xF8, 0x4A, 0xD8, 0x74, 0x06, 0xD4, 0x18, 0x4E, 0x7B, 0xAD, 0xB0, 0xFA, 0xAE, 0x6B, 0x7C, 0x59, 0x6F, 0xCA, 0xD3, 0xF6, 0x67, 0x1B, 0x82, 0x95, 0xB3, 0x46, 0x5F, 0x43, 0x44, 0x9F, 0x24, 0x9D, 0x7B, 0x2E, 0x24, 0xE2, 0x8B, 0x10, 0x17, 0xC7, 0x7E, 0x78, 0xF7, 0x45, 0x25, 0xF8, 0xAF, 0x96, 0xE6, 0x2C, 0x1B, 0xCB, 0x01, 0xEC, 0x45, 0xB2, 0xE4, 0x45, 0x11, 0xB9, 0xBB, 0xB0, 0x1A, 0xF9, 0x5B, 0x75, 0xE4, 0x33, 0x12, 0xBE, 0xA9, 0xE2, 0x5C, 0x7B, 0x00, 0xC3, 0xBF, 0x70, 0x3F, 0xDC, 0x5B, 0x88, 0x4E, 0xB8, 0xEB, 0xED, 0xCA, 0x9E, 0xF0, 0x4E, 0xD2, 0x80, 0x1E, 0xB4, 0xA3, 0xAC, 0x4B, 0xD2, 0x30, 0x13, 0xED, 0x09, 0x9B, 0xB4, 0x6A, 0x61, 0x15, 0x4A, 0x1C, 0x38, 0x96, 0x2D, 0x73, 0x66, 0xD8, 0x0F, 0xB4, 0x5F, 0xE9, 0x12, 0xF5, 0x7C, 0xFD, 0x0E, 0xC5, 0xC1, 0x02, 0xE1, 0xB0, 0x7E, 0xDE, 0x3B, 0x47, 0x76, 0x3A, 0x80, 0x7A, 0xCF, 0xD4, 0xBF, 0xA1, 0x88, 0x4C, 0xD1, 0x52, 0xD4, 0xC4, 0xE0, 0x07, 0x5F, 0x03, 0xE3, 0xC7, 0x6B, 0x51, 0x82, 0x99, 0x72, 0x28, 0x06, 0x19, 0xDB, 0xC0, 0x03, 0x62, 0xBC, 0xC4, 0x54, 0xE9, 0x54, 0x3A, 0xD3, 0x52, 0xF3, 0x02, 0x9D, 0x9D, 0xF6, 0xD2, 0x72, 0x62, 0xB8, 0x88, 0xA8, 0x65, 0x74, 0x80, 0x0A, 0x82, 0xB3, 0x02, 0x82, 0x01, 0x01, 0x00, 0xCB, 0x7C, 0xEC, 0xAA, 0x10, 0x97, 0xB1, 0xA8, 0x60, 0x0A, 0xE3, 0x61, 0xF9, 0x26, 0x2F, 0xAD, 0x88, 0xFA, 0x7C, 0x40, 0x05, 0xE0, 0xD5, 0xBB, 0x2A, 0xCE, 0x68, 0x90, 0xF2, 0xAC, 0x8B, 0x63, 0x29, 0x7F, 0xA0, 0x61, 0xC6, 0xDB, 0xBC, 0xB1, 0x20, 0x53, 0xC5, 0xEC, 0xAC, 0x04, 0xEC, 0x29, 0xBD, 0xDE, 0x4F, 0xBA, 0x55, 0x66, 0x0D, 0x25, 0xB7, 0x3E, 0xED, 0x0F, 0xCE, 0x7C, 0x43, 0x30, 0xC1, 0xDD, 0xAA, 0x50, 0x8D, 0xA9, 0x6B, 0x1C, 0x85, 0xCB, 0x24, 0xD4, 0xCA, 0xA2, 0x8F, 0x3F, 0x68, 0x0F, 0xEF, 0x86, 0x24, 0x3F, 0xA8, 0x9B, 0x65, 0x8D, 0xF4, 0x5E, 0x84, 0x57, 0x1D, 0x85, 0xBC, 0xC1, 0x49, 0x3F, 0xD5, 0x94, 0x9D, 0xA7, 0x63, 0x70, 0xA9, 0x0F, 0x29, 0x4D, 0x60, 0x80, 0x4A, 0xC0, 0x22, 0xCD, 0x1D, 0x5E, 0x0D, 0x65, 0xC2, 0xF2, 0x37, 0xA3, 0x81, 0x63, 0x2B, 0xD5, 0x38, 0x40, 0x63, 0xC2, 0x52, 0xC8, 0xA5, 0xA7, 0x06, 0xBD, 0xF9, 0xC3, 0xF8, 0x43, 0x84, 0xC0, 0x6E, 0x86, 0x03, 0x5E, 0xBE, 0xF8, 0x79, 0x7E, 0x1C, 0x2C, 0x93, 0x07, 0x35, 0xEB, 0xBA, 0x84, 0xF7, 0xAE, 0xC5, 0x9C, 0xB7, 0xAD, 0x31, 0x7D, 0xBB, 0x9C, 0x20, 0xAC, 0x8F, 0xD6, 0xB9, 0x63, 0xAE, 0xDC, 0xE3, 0x75, 0xF1, 0x41, 0x18, 0x5F, 0xCA, 0x35, 0x52, 0xFD, 0xD0, 0x8C, 0x75, 0xA6, 0x6C, 0xE1, 0x31, 0x2D, 0x11, 0x9A, 0x0D, 0x7B, 0x83, 0x04, 0xB3, 0xA1, 0x88, 0x3C, 0x2E, 0xF9, 0xD8, 0x5E, 0x10, 0x29, 0xE0, 0x3C, 0xBF, 0x4E, 0xFD, 0x7A, 0xC3, 0xF5, 0x19, 0x37, 0x41, 0x42, 0x88, 0x67, 0x4D, 0xB2, 0x99, 0x25, 0xAA, 0xC5, 0x5F, 0xE6, 0x9D, 0x47, 0x95, 0xE7, 0x86, 0x04, 0xF4, 0xA5, 0xE2, 0xC1, 0x61, 0x6F, 0x81, 0x0E, 0x4B, 0x21, 0x69, 0x45, 0x73, 0xA7, 0x0D, 0x6B};

    DWORD keyBufferLength = sizeof(privKey);

    CHAR encrypted[KEY_BUFFER_LENGTH];
    DWORD encryptedLength = KEY_BUFFER_LENGTH;
    CryptStringToBinaryA(encryptedBase64, strlen(encryptedBase64), CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, (LPBYTE)encrypted, &encryptedLength, NULL, NULL);


    if (CryptAcquireContextA(&provider, NULL, MS_ENHANCED_PROV_A, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT) == TRUE)
    {
        DWORD derSize = 0;
        BYTE *privateKeyInfo;
        if (CryptDecodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING, PKCS_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, privKey, keyBufferLength, CRYPT_DECODE_ALLOC_FLAG, NULL, &privateKeyInfo, &derSize) != FALSE)
        {
            HCRYPTKEY key = 0;
            if (CryptImportKey(provider, privateKeyInfo, derSize, 0, CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_OAEP, &key) != FALSE)
            {
                if (CryptDecrypt(key, NULL, TRUE, CRYPT_OAEP, (LPBYTE) encrypted, &encryptedLength) != FALSE)
                {
                    encrypted[encryptedLength] = '\0';
                    printf("%s\n", encrypted);
                }
                else
                {
                    DWORD error = GetLastError();
                    printf("%d\n", error);
                }
                CryptDestroyKey(key);
            }
            LocalFree(privateKeyInfo);
        }

        CryptReleaseContext(provider, 0);
    }
}
```

Could you please tell, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: `SymCryptRsaCoreVerifyInput` set this error on your data. so simply bad data for decrypt

Comment: Are you running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Nope, I use Windows 10.